# How can I fix "sh: apt-get command not found"?

Tags: linux, apt, buildroot

I just succeded to run [pulpino](https://github.com/pulp-platform/pulpino) on [Zedboard](https://store.digilentinc.com/zedboard-zynq-7000-arm-fpga-soc-development-board/) FPGA and I managed to boot an OS on it. But, the problem that there no **apt-get** command. I checked the following:

```
$ uname -a
Linux buildroot 3.18.0-xilinx #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jun 12 12:19:13 CEST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux

$ echo $PATH
/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin

$ ls /bin/
ash            dnsdomainname  linux64        nice           sleep
busybox        dumpkmap       ln             pidof          stty
cat            echo           login          ping           su
catv           egrep          ls             pipe_progress  sync
chattr         false          lsattr         printenv       tar
chgrp          fdflush        mkdir          ps             touch
chmod          fgrep          mknod          pwd            true
chown          getopt         mktemp         rm             umount
cp             grep           more           rmdir          uname
cpio           gunzip         mount          run-parts      usleep
date           gzip           mountpoint     sed            vi
dd             hostname       mt             setarch        watch
df             kill           mv             setserial      zcat
dmesg          linux32        netstat        sh


$ ls /bin/
ash            dnsdomainname  linux64        nice           sleep
busybox        dumpkmap       ln             pidof          stty
cat            echo           login          ping           su
catv           egrep          ls             pipe_progress  sync
chattr         false          lsattr         printenv       tar
chgrp          fdflush        mkdir          ps             touch
chmod          fgrep          mknod          pwd            true
chown          getopt         mktemp         rm             umount
cp             grep           more           rmdir          uname
cpio           gunzip         mount          run-parts      usleep
date           gzip           mountpoint     sed            vi
dd             hostname       mt             setarch        watch
df             kill           mv             setserial      zcat
dmesg          linux32        netstat        sh


$ ls /usr/bin/
[            du           less         readlink     ssh-agent    unzip
[[           eject        logger       realpath     ssh-keygen   uptime
ar           env          logname      renice       ssh-keyscan  uudecode
awk          expr         lsof         reset        strings      uuencode
basename     find         lspci        resize       tail         vlock
bunzip2      flock        lsusb        rx           tee          wc
bzcat        fold         lzcat        scp          telnet       wget
chrt         free         lzma         seq          test         which
chvt         fuser        md5sum       setkeycodes  tftp         who
cksum        gdbserver    mesg         setsid       time         whoami
clear        head         microcom     sftp         top          xargs
cmp          hexdump      mkfifo       sha1sum      tr           xz
crontab      hostid       nohup        sha256sum    traceroute   xzcat
cut          id           nslookup     sha3sum      tty          yes
dc           install      od           sha512sum    uniq
deallocvt    ipcrm        openvt       slogin       unix2dos
diff         ipcs         passwd       sort         unlink
dirname      killall      patch        ssh          unlzma
dos2unix     last         printf       ssh-add      unxz


$ ls /usr/sbin/
addgroup     chroot       deluser      fbset        killall5     readprofile
adduser      crond        dnsd         fdformat     loadfont     setlogcons
arping       delgroup     ether-wake   inetd        rdate        sshd
```

So everything looks good except for the apt-get command.
Anyone have an idea  to fix it.

Comment: What are the results of `lsb_release -a` or `cat /etc/*-release`?

Comment: NAME=Buildroot
VERSION=2015.05
ID=buildroot
VERSION_ID=2015.05
PRETTY_NAME="Buildroot 2015.05"

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17701885/11639109

Comment: if i remember correctly, the buildroot linux does not have any default package manager. Try to google how to build apt-get on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [Buildroot](https://www.buildroot.org/)-generated system, and those don’t come with a package manager. The whole idea is that you make your package selection in the build, not on the system running the generated image. Don’t try to install a package manager on your embedded system; instead, figure out how to modify the build (on the build system) to add the software you need.

In fact, Buildroot doesn’t even use packages in the generated image; the reasons for this are [explained in the FAQ](https://www.buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#faq-no-binary-packages).